# Jenkins job wait for first successful build of other job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that should not start building until another job has been built successfully at least once. They are not related per se, so I don't want to use triggers. Is there a way to do this?

Some background: I'm using SCM polling to trigger the second job. I've looked at the Files Found Trigger plugin, but that would keep on triggering the second job after the first on has been built. I've also found the Run Condition Plugin, but that seems to work only on build steps, not on the entire build.

**Update** - The second job copies artifacts from the first job. As long as the first job has never completed successfully, the Copy Artifact step fails. I am trying to prevent that failure, by not even attempting to build the second job until the first job has completed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Block queued job plugin* can be used for this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin

Comment: Unfortunately that plugin is not supported by Jenkins Job Builder.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

You can create a new flow job and use this DSL:

[image]

I've used 10 in the retry section but you can use any numbers.

This flow job can be triggered by monitoring the same SCM URL of your second job.

**Update**, here is a second solution.

You can use the [HTTP Request plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin).

If you want to test that your first job has been built successfully **at least once**, you can test this URL:
http://your.jenkins.instance/job/your.job/lastSuccessfulBuild/

One example:

[image]

[image]

As my build has never been successful, the lastSuccessfulBuild URL doesn't exist. The HTTP Request changes my build status to failure.

Does it help?

Comment: This has the downside that it would build the first job every time there is a change in the second job.

Comment: I've added a second solution.

Comment: Well, that would work, but it still tries to build the second job, giving a failure. I would like the second job not to be tried until the first job has completed once. I noticed I had not explained this properly, so I've updated the question.

Comment: I've already found that the Block Queued Job plugin does what I want, more or less.

Comment: OK nice to hear you found a solution :)